# Failed to instantiate kendo.directives module

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having an issue loading my kendo script via Angular. The error is:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
> kendo.directives due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'kendo.directives' is not available!
> You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
> registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
> second argument.

This is how I tried to load my module:

```
angular.module('ar', ["kendo.directives"]).controller('InventoryController', InventoryController);
```

In my HTML page the Kendo script is called this way:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/2014.1.528/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: You can check in dev tools that the script really loads, for starters.

Comment: The script loads when I look at the list of sources. Is there is any other way to check that it is being referenced?

Comment: I believe you will also need to reference `kendo.angular.min.js`.